# JsonResult action not being fired

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, jsonresult

I have an action method in my `UpdatesController` with the following signature:

```
public JsonResult GetUpdates(DateTime lastUpdate)
```

In my view, I have the following code to call the method (at this moment in time it's just on a button's onclick event for testing, the button having id clickme):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
        alert("Before");
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Updates/GetUpdates", "04/05/2011 11:44:37", function(data){ alert(data); });
        alert("After");
    });
});
```

The click event fires, and the `Before` and `After` alert's both fire, however I don't get any data back as I get no alert with json data. I have also set a breakpoint in the `GetUpdates` method and the breakpoint is never hit, which I believe indicates that the request isn't getting sent?

Could there be some issue with the parameter?

Thanks

**Update**

So I finally got it to step through in Visual Studio and the action method runs with no errors. However, the alert isn't shown and if I look at the Net tab in Firebug I get a 500 error for this specific request?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this in firebug? Does 'http://localhost/Updates/GetUpdates' get called?

Comment: @Simon G I can step over the line without any error, I'm not sure how I would check that it's definitely being called though?

Comment: Change the way you write your url may be it works. http://localhost/Updates/GetUpdates to something like /Updates/GetUpdates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to do this:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/Updates/GetUpdates", { lastUpdate: "04/05/2011 11:44:37" }, function(data){ alert(data); });
```

It's possible it's not finding the correct action as there may not be a matching route.

Running [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and checking what the response is would be the next step I would try

Edit:

Also make sure that your Json call has JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as a parameter if you're using MVC 2. e.g.

```
return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: @AndyC That's strange, try running fiddler and to see what the response from the server is. Although, you should also be able to check in the Net tab in firebug.

Comment: Odd, I'm getting a 500 error. Strange that I can't step through this in visual studio though.

Comment: Actually, I did just get it to step through and got no error. Ill update the question.

Comment: Got it! I had to AllowGet in my action method in MVC, was a security feature blocking it. Edit: just like in your answer, I must have missed that bit!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. That one caught me out when I first started using MVC 2.